# How to use a variable in API payload in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, variables, jupyter-notebook

I'm using Jupyter Notebook to gather up a bunch of API calls then use various plotting tools to generate pretty graphs.

I have the notebook working great when using constants in the API payload.  Now I'm trying to replace the constants with user entered variables and having some challenges.

The following method for variable use works when the variable isn't part of a filter or function:

`key = input('Enter your subscription API Key then press Enter: ')`

When prompted, the user enters the key and that value is used perfectly fine in the following:

```
headers = {
   'X-Co-Integration-Key': key,
   'Content-Type': "application/json",
   'Cache-Control': "no-cache",
   }
```

Next, enter another variable for a guide called guideId:

```
guideId = input('Enter the Guide ID of the guide for which you want statistics then press Enter: ')
```

When prompted, the user enters the guideId and that value is stored, but I can't seem to get it to be used properly in the API payload.

I've tried several different methods of inserting the variable and the following gets me the closest to something that works:

```
{\n                \"filter\": \"id== \"" + guideId + "\n            }
```

The API call runs, but I get the following error:

```
{"overall": {"DeserializationError": "invalid character 'q' after object key:value pair"}, "fields": {"pipeline": "Required"}}
```

It looks like it is reading the variable and stopping after it hits the first character in the variable, which, in this case is a `q`.

I tried changing the variable to start with a number.  No change in behavior.

I tried using `str(guideId)` - no change in behavior.

I'm stumped.  Any ideas?